# MVC Razor - Default Value as Current date for textbox type date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, date, razor

I have a `Textbox` with type as `date`. I am trying to set default value of the `textbox` to current date.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date, new { @id = "Date", @type = "date", 
                                    @value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })
```

The above line doesn't set default value. How to set default value as current date?

Comment: Just set the value of `Date` in your model before passing it to the view.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As Stephen Muecke said, you need to set the property's value on the model.

```
// in controller method that returns the view.
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.Date = DateTime.Today;

return View(model);
```

And your Razor would be:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date"})
```

Note that the `id` and the `name` properties should be automatically assigned to the property name when using a `For` method, such as `@Html.TextBoxFor()`, so you don't need to explicitly set the `id` attribute.

Comment: I suspect OP may not want property `Date` to be a `string`. Instead, set the property to `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today` and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control"})` Only set `@type = "date"` if your want to render the browsers datepicker (in which case the format must be `yyyy-MM-dd`)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke i do wanted it in `Date` format...I used `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}` & then only it worked..as HTML5 input date expects the date in the RFC3339 format....!

Comment: @Anup, Just be aware that IE has some problems using this so worth testing in all browsers.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I always prefer data to be a string when sending it to the view.  All formatting happens in the controller so very minimal logic exists in the view.

Answer (score 31):

It's better way to manage in view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.Date, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Thanks for your answer.   It's best to format code, in the way you can see I've done, for ease of reading.

Comment: Works perfect for what I need

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. straight to the point and easier to implement.

Answer (score 5):

`<input asp-for="date" value="@DateTime.Today" type="datetime" class="form-control" />`

This works for me. Remember to change 'date' according to your model.

and use this, if you need time as well

`<input asp-for="date" value="@DateTime.Now" type="datetime" class="form-control" />`

Answer (score 2):

in your controller use this:

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.Date = model.date == null ? DateTime.Today : model.date;

return View(model);
```

in your view page

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
 new { 
   @class = "form-control", 
   type = "date"
})
```

Comment: Great solution. This was the only thing that worked for me. FYI, I didn't have to do the controller stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Another Solution:**

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.CreatedOn, new{@value= System.DateTime.Now})
```

It works on my end, sure it will work on yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var dateNewFormat, onlyDate, today = new Date();

        dateNewFormat = today.getFullYear() + '-';
        if (today.getMonth().length == 2) {

            dateNewFormat += (today.getMonth() + 1);
        }
        else {
            dateNewFormat += '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1);
        }

        onlyDate = today.getDate();
        if (onlyDate.toString().length == 2) {

            dateNewFormat += "-" + onlyDate;
        }
        else {
            dateNewFormat += '-0' + onlyDate;
        }

        $('#mydate').val(dateNewFormat);
    });
```

Comment: It's always better to do any processing on the server side though.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this script in your view

An your razor your razor page would be like

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        var date = new Date();

        var Mes = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        var Dia = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var Anio = date.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById("currentDate").value = Anio + "-" + Mes + "-" + Dia;
    };
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line"  id="currentDate" name="currentDate" type="date" value="">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

window.onload = function () {
var date = new Date();

```
    var Mes = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    var Dia = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var Anio = date.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("currentDate").value = Anio + "-" + Mes + "-" + Dia;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?