# Setting Default time in MVC 5 time input field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to set default time to 12:00 AM on the input box, I have tried all sorts of stuff but its still displaying blank.

.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" label-for="Reminder">Time</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reminder, new { @type = "time", @value = "12:00 AM", @class = "form-control", required = "", @placeholder = "12:00 AM" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Reminder, "", new { @class = "text-danger error-text" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Time Input field]

Comment: value for input type time is 24 format so value should be `12:00` or `13:00` something like this without AM or PM .. you can take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: Maybe a duplicate for this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418120/mvc-razor-default-value-as-current-date-for-textbox-type-date

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef if I use the <input type="time"> as per the example its working but I want to use Html.TextBoxFor since I want to bind value from the model if value exists.

Comment: @YashSoni I have set the property's value on the model, on the developer tools I can see the default value but on the text box its still blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.time, new { @Type = "time", @Value = "22:15:00" })
```

Try:

type -> Type

value -> Value